# Configure a external Angular lib with .forRoot() that depends on a main Application service for populate config values

Tags: angular, ng-modules, angular-providers, injection-tokens

I have a custom Library that needs custom configuration within the forRoot() Library module, but I need to use an App Config Module that loads that configuration asynchronously instead of using static injected data as following.

```
// Custom Library module

@NgModule({})
export class FormatModule {
    constructor() {}

    public static forRoot(config: FormatConfig) {
        // Do something with the config
    }
}
```

where FormatConfig is the following:

```
export interface FormatConfig {
    [key: string]: any
}
```

Usage of that module within the main AppModule:

```
export function loadConfig(configService): Observable<FormatConfig> {
    return configService.extractFormatConfig();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormatModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I also have an Injection Token to assign the config data:

```
export const FORMAT_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<string>('FORMAT_CONFIG');
```

Is possible to use the forRoot method and a factory to populate the data which the module needs. I won’t inject the ConfigService inside the FormatModule, because that would make the FormatModule dependant of another external service.

Answer (score 2):

define injection token

```
export const FORMAT_CONFIG: InjectionToken<FormatConfig> = new InjectionToken<FormatConfig>('FORMAT_CONFIG');
```

use your factory when declaring the AppModule

```
export function loadConfig(configService: ConfigService): Observable<FormatConfig> {
    return configService.extractFormatConfig();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormatModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: FORMAT_CONFIG,
    useFactory: loadConfig,
    deps: [ConfigService]
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

now you can inject your config inside your `FormatModule` like the following

...

```
constructor(@Inject(FORMAT_CONFIG) private formatConfig: FormatConfig)
```

Comment: My `FormatModule` is inside `SharedModule`. What should be approach for that?